# How can I sample from a shifted and scaled Student-t distribution with a specified mean and sd in R?

Tags: r, simulation, prior, t-distribution, brms

I'm currently building some Bayesian models with the `brms` package and the default intercept prior is `student_t(3, 0, 6.3)` and so I'm looking to visualise the prior predictive distribution from this prior. Typically I would just use functions like `rnorm` or `unif` depending on the distribution; however, the `rt` function only takes  `n` and `df` arguments and I cannot specify an SD of 6.3.

How can I sample from this distribution?

Comment: @Zen This is incorrect (if you meant the standard deviation by $\sigma$) as $t_\nu$ has variance $\frac{\nu}{\nu-2}$. It should be `x <- mu + sigma * sqrt((df-2)/df) * rt(n, df)`.

Comment: The alternative compound Gaussian approach is to first generate `s<-1/rgamma(n,df/2,(df-2)*sigma^2/2)` and then `x<-rnorm(n,mu,s)`.

Comment: To clarify, the comments and answers suggest how to sample from a shifted and scaled Student-$t$ distribution, and this is probably what the OP intends. (I have edited the title accordingly.) This is different from sampling from a Student-$t$ distribution that is shifted but not scaled and where we know the sd from which we can derive the d.f. parameter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While that $6.3$ seems not to mean the standard deviation in Stan, if that's what you want to do...

...do it in multiple steps.

1. Simulate from the t-distribution with the appropriate degrees of freedom $\nu$, using `rt`.
2. Divide by the population standard deviation, $\sqrt{\frac{
   \nu
   }{
   \nu-2
   }}$. Now the population standard deviation is $1$.
3. Multiply by your desired standard deviation.
4. Add your desired mean, since the population mean is $0$.

You can combine these steps in one function.

```
rt_modified <- function(N, nu, mu, standard_dev){
    x1 <- rt(N, nu) # 1
    x2 <- x1/sqrt(nu/(nu-2)) # 2
    x3 <- x2 * standard_dev # 3
    x4 <- x3 + mu # 4
    return(x4)
}
```

Comment: Breaking it up into the four steps makes perfect sense, thanks a lot @Dave, much appreciated!

Comment: This is wrong. @fisher-j is the correct answer. The original poster is asking specifically how to generate samples in R equivalent to the samples that Stan generates for the purpose of visualizing a prior in R.  The method that you suggest will not produce equivalent samples to what Stan sampler will produce. This matters because many Stan default prior recommendations (e.g. for logit-scale parameters ) make use of the Student-t.

Answer (score 2):

I tried @Dave answer, and got different results than those predicted by the [random number generator used by Stan](https://mc-stan.org/docs/functions-reference/student-t-distribution.html) which is how priors are sampled when using `brms::brm` with `sample_priors = TRUE`.

The r function [`rt`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/TDist.html) has a non-centrality parameter which gives similar results to stan when the scale of the stan `student_t_rng` function is set to 1, but doesn't support a "scale" parameter.

The function [`ggdist::rstudent_t`](https://mjskay.github.io/ggdist/reference/student_t.html) is defined as:

```r
function (n, df, mu = 0, sigma = 1) 
{
    rt(n, df = df) * sigma + mu
}
```

We can test the stan function using the `rstan` package by exporting our own version of the stan student t random number generator. I'm using $DF = 3$, $\mu = 2$, and $\sigma = 2$.

```r
library(rstan)

model_code <- "
  functions {
    real stan_student_t_rng() {
      return student_t_rng(3, 2, 2);
    }
  }
  model {} 
"
expose_stan_functions(stanc(model_code = model_code))
```

And compare the results of the different approaches.

```r
y1 <- rt_modified(1e4, 3, 2, 2)
y2 <- ggdist::rstudent_t(1e4, 3, 2, 2)
y3 <- sapply(numeric(1e4), \(x) stan_student_t_rng())
quantile(y1, c(0.05, 0.5, 0.95))
quantile(y2, c(0.05, 0.5, 0.95))
quantile(y3, c(0.05, 0.5, 0.95))

#                           5%       50%      95%
# rt_modified        -1.209507 0.1514803 1.513690
# rstudent_t         -2.601524 2.0410839 6.845778
# stan_student_t_rng -2.631746 2.0084448 6.712253
```

It would seem there is a difference in the interpretation of these two different approaches, but to get results similar to Stan, specifically the priors returned by `brms::brm` with `sample_priors = TRUE`, we can use the method used by `ggdist::rstudent_t`.

Comment: That `rstudent_t` function does not divide by the population variance. I will not say that the function is wrong to do what it does, but skipping that step represents a different procedure than the function I gave, and that procedure is not what the original question seeks. To use that function means that `sigma` must consider both the targeted standard deviation and the standard deviation of $t_{\nu}$, which is the $\sqrt{\dfrac{\nu}{\nu - 2}}$ in the answer I posted.

Comment: `sigma` is a scale parameter, *but it is not the standard deviation.*  There's nothing invalid about that--it's just a different parameterization.  To get results similar to Stan, you have to account for that, as Dave explained in the answer.

Comment: @whuber stan uses this pdf: $\text{StudentT}(y|\nu,\mu,\sigma) = \frac{\Gamma\left((\nu + 1)/2\right)} {\Gamma(\nu/2)} \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{\nu \pi} \ \sigma}
\ \left( 1 + \frac{1}{\nu} \left(\frac{y - \mu}{\sigma}\right)^2
\right)^{-(\nu + 1)/2} $ . Does this reflect the same parameterization used in their random number generator where $\sigma$ is a scale and *not* the SD?

Comment: In that parameterization, $\sigma$ is not the SD: it rescales the standard student t distribution, whose SD is $\sqrt{\nu/(\nu-2)}.$ It's a good choice because all student t distributions with $\nu\le 2$ have *infinite* standard deviations.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the original poster's question. While the original poster did use the term "SD", meaning standard deviation is it clear from the context that they are interested in sampling from a student-t distribution with scale term set to 6.3. In Stan, the arguments for the function student_t(nu, mu, sigma) clearly specify that sigma is a scale term. So the original poster is asking for an R equivalent to the Stan function student_t(3, 0, 6.3).